# Aptana Studio 3: How to get rid of brighter whitespace background sections?

Tags: ide, aptana3

Developing in Aptana 3 I get some whitespace colored brighter than the regular background, as if I have it selected. This is really annoying and makes it difficult to read the code.

[image: Aptana Studio 3 screen-shot]

Any thoughts on how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 2):

Other themes provide this sort of white space reveal so it must be possible.  Might try exporting one of the themes that does, peering into that export and seeing if you can reverse engineer.

Otherwise, grab a theme that does and tweak it to suit your needs.

Unless you've found another solution - this is a bit late.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a different theme. Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Themes.

Comment: This theme is very comfortable, at first I though it to be good for nothing, but then I realized that soft dark background has it's benefits. White background and high-contrast text strains your eyes.

Comment: I agree. However, the lighter gray whitespace doesn't bother me. You can change the theme on a per item basis too. I don't want to weed through the options for you. There are also other dark themes that don't have this like Monokai Dark.

Comment: That is the first place I looked in. I went through each setting and tried changing it, but I can't seem to find the right one.